Continuity and derivability of integral function
In a certain exercise I have been asked to show that the function defined by the following integral is continuous and derivable in $t \in (0,\infty)$:
$$F(t) =  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}$$
It seems clear for me that the function is continuous because all the functions that appear inside the integral so are. Of course, this is not enough to justify it. What I am most lost with is the fact that it is derivable. I'm not sure if I can exchange integral and derivative w.r.t $t$. By the way, in the statement of the exercise I'm given as indication to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but in my case I don't know how to apply it here. Could somebody give me a hint?

Hint: when trying to check derivability from the definition, try to "put everything in the integral", then try to use the DCT.

By "from the definition", do you mean trying to compute the usual limit that defines the derivative of a function, right?

Yes, that's exactly it.

I tried, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I obtain $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot (e^{-hx}-1)}{h}$

Yes, so now it comes down to an exchange integral-limit which the DCT is useful for.

For example, defining $h = \frac{1}{k}$ so then the limit is with $k \to \infty$?

I guess technically you do need to consider all sequences $(h_k)_k$ with $h_k \to 0^+$ when $k \to \infty$ but yes that's the idea.
